# When is the kernel of A equal to the kernel of A squared?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

If A is a square matrix, when is its kernel equal to the kernel of A squared?

I think it is when the intersection of im(A) and ker(A) equals the set with only the zero vector, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Is $A$ a matrix? a linear operator? Put us into a context in order to give an adequate answer

Comment: Sorry, A is a linear transformation from Rn to Rn.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please use MathJax to format your posts for readability. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly  $\;ker A \subset \ker A^2\;$ since

$$x\in\ker A\implies A^2x=A(Ax)=A0=0\implies x\in\ker A^2$$

Now, if $\;\ker A^2\subset \ker A\;$ , then $\;A^2x=0\implies Ax=0\;$ , and if $\;w\in\ker A\cap\text{Im}\,A\;$ , then

$$\exists y\;\;s.t.\:\;Ay=w\implies A^2y=Aw=0\implies w=Ay=0\implies \text{Im}\,A\,\cap\,\ker A=\{0\}$$

The other direction ($\;\text{Im}\,A\,\cap\,\ker A=\{0\}\implies \ker A^2\subset \ker A\;)\;$ follows from

$$x\in\ker A^2\implies 0=A^2x=A(Ax)\implies Ax\in\text{Im}\,A\,\cap\,\ker A=\{0\}\implies Ax=0\implies x\in\ker A$$

Comment: This assumes $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @ndhanson3 I can't see from where you see that...maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: $A^2y=Aw=0\implies w=Ay=0$ requires $A$ to be invertible. Counterexample is $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ with $w=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ in its kernel and $y=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Kernel of $A$ is multiples of $w$, and kernel of $A^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is everything.

Comment: @ndhanson3 I think you're confusing things: $\;A^2y=Aw=0\implies w=Ay=0\;$ because we're assuming $\;\ker A^2\subset\ker A\;$ ...! Thus, $$\;A^2y=0\implies y\in\ker A^2\subset\ker A\implies y\in\ker A\implies Ay=0\;\ldots$$ This is the same as $\;w=0\;$ and etc.

Comment: In the example you give we obviously have **not** $\;\ker A^2\subset\ker A\;$ ,since $\;A^2=0\;$ ...

Comment: I think it is always a good idea to avoid downvoting when something "is wrong"...or when it looks like it is wrong. Sometimes we can miss something...